# Was there ever a published "world of tarrasques"?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, product-identification

Sometimes I pick in some discussions hints about a "Tarrasque planet". Is it an official place? Was it published in what book / magazine / source material?

P.S.: I know the default stance is to take sources like Dragon Magazine as unofficial reference material, but **for the scope of this question** so long it was published or licensed by the copyright owners, it is "official".

Answer (score 13):

## The crystal sphere Falx

Featured in 2nd edition D&D's Spelljammer book *Practical Planetology*, the planet Falx is an Earth-like planet with a single large continent and a high carbon dioxide concentration.

It is populated with hundreds of creatures that are *very similar to* the tarrasque, but are not the tarrasque. I cannot find a particular image or description of how they are different; from memory, they are smaller.

The book features 5 different adventure ideas for the planet, and mentions a variety of other threats (myconids, illithids, mobile plants) but the one everyone remembers is the tarrasque analog.

Comment: No, they are exactly like the tarrasque. "Some sages claim that this world is the home of the tarrasque, and that the unique creature is actually a single specimen transported through space for some reason."

Comment: Maybe it is like Highlander (you know the bad dream that even the directors want to forget) perhaps *our* Terrasque is just a felon from his world and is serving time here...